# Explaining the output in this context

Tags: ruby

```
def dog
  return "apple"
  return "orange"
end

dog
```

Hi, why does the output return only "apple", shouldn't it return both "apple" and "orange" ? I am fairly new to programming, help will be appreciated.

Comment: `return` tells the program to stop executing the method and return the value given to `return`, which in this case is `"apple"`. If you want both strings `"apple"` and `"orange"` you should probably return an array `return %w[apple orange]`

Comment: Use two spaces for indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` tells the program to stop executing the method and return the value given to `return`, which in this case is `"apple"`. If you want both strings `"apple"` and `"orange"` you should probably return an array.

```
def dog
  return %w[apple orange]
end
```

Also, Ruby returns the last line in a method which makes the `return` unnecessary. You can simply write the following.

```
def dog
  %w[apple orange]
end
```

Generally, in Ruby, return is used to stop executing a method if a condition is met or not met. Something like the following.

```
def dog(likes_fruit = true)
  return [] if likes_fruit == false
  # return [] unless likes_fruit # (this is the same as above, but unless can be confusing when learning ruby)
  %w[apple orange]
end
```

Comment: <def batman_ironman_lambda
  victor = lambda { return "Batman will win!" }
  victor.call
  "Iron Man will win!"
end

puts batman_ironman_lambda> Why is it that in this case the output will be "Iron Man will win" instead of "Batman will win"? Because you mentioned that "return tells the program to stop executing the method and return the value given to return". Since , "Batman will win" comes first followed by "Iron man will win", so when ruby return "Batman will win" first, shouldn't ruby tells the program to stop executing the method and return the value "Batman will win"?

Comment: Pardon me for the formatting of my comment(question), it is my first time using this website. I will learn the formatting when i have time. And I hope my question make sense.

Comment: @roppo this is because your lambda is a different context as your `batman_ironman_lambda` and the return inside the lambda doesn't affect your method but rather the execution of the lambda. Perhaps what you want is a `Proc` instead of a lambda. Take a look at this article in the "The return keyword works exactly how you'd expect" section. http://blog.honeybadger.io/using-lambdas-in-ruby/

Comment: @Baylor_rae, Hi I have read the article but I dont understand what you mean by "my lambda is a diff context as your batman_ironman_lamda" and what do you mean by " the return inside the lambda doesn't affect your method but rather the execution of the lambda ". I am not looking for proc, I am just trying to understand why. Thanks in advance.